# Export a pandas dataframe to a sortable table in HTML

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

Is there a way to export a pandas dataframe into an HTML file and incorporate some additional code that makes the output sortable by column?

I have been using Dash DataTable to give the user the option to sort the results, but I was wondering if there is another way in which a server running is not needed and the user can just load the HTML page and sort the results.

So far I have been able to have semi interactive plots based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868987/plotly-saving-multiple-plots-into-a-single-html), but I would like to add also sortable tables in the HTML and after searching online I am not clear what is the best way to do it (still a newbie with HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting you have to [use JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript) and for the exporting part use method [pandas.DataFrame.to_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html).

Comment: Do you have any reference link on what is the proper way to incorporate JavaScript for the sorting?

Comment: pandas.Dataframe.to_html() will convert the Dataframe into <table> element.After that you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript SO answer for sorting purpose.

Comment: If this worked out for you then please mark it as accepted so that others can take advantage of it.

Comment: It didn't work yet: I am new to JS and when I tried the code in the post mentioned (and wrapped the script into `<script> `</script>` and `window.onload=function()` ) and it still not working. I'll accept the answer when I figure out why is not working or when a working snippet is provided in this post.

Comment: @datapug Hi datapug, thank you for asking the questions. I literally face the same issue to you right now. I use pandas.to_html to display my df in html, and trying to find someway to make the columns in the table can be sorted. May I ask if you finally find a result for this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I used [panel](https://panel.holoviz.org/) for this purpose (version 0.14.2). It creates sortable HTML tables by default.

```
import panel as pn
# df denotes your existing pandas DataFrame
df = pn.widgets.Tabulator(df)
# df.datetime = df.datetime.astype(str)
df.save("df.html")
```

If you have columns which are datetimes or timedeltas it may be best to cast them to string first for more sensible representation.

If you wish for a timedelta to be sortable it is best to convert it to a sensible integer.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'panel.widgets' has no attribute 'Tabulator'